# Android Close Activity After All Dialogs Are Dismissed

Tags: android

I have an activity that I call with startActivityForResult and pass in extras with 2 values.
These 2 values determine what functionality to run, for example the values are checked and methods such as 
add a calendar event, create an alarm etc are called
These methods display AlertDialogs allowing input

**I want the activity to only return the intent once all these tasks have been completed and processed. I am not sure of how to check if the activity has completed**

Is there a way to check if all Dialogs created by the activity are dismissed before closing the activity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little confusing without some code of what you are doing, however, you can check in `finish()` to see if the `Dialogs` are showing

```
@Override
public void finish()
{
     if (myDialogObject.isShowing())
     {
         // do something or nothing
     }
     else
     {
        // do something else 
     }
}
```

You can also set an `OnDismissListener` on your `Dialog`(s).

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I correct interpreted your question, you want that your Activity close when the dialogs completed their work. I think the best way to do it is passing the Activity in the creation of the dialogs (via MyDialog.newInstance(this) method) and then using a callback method in your Activity in order to let the dialogs to notify their completion.

If you provide some code it will be easier to understand whether this is what you're searching for.